# How to shift to another fragment from tab fragment created using view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I created three tabs with three fragments using view pager.I want to jump to inspiring fragment after clicking on list item defined inside Categories Fragment(Tab Fragment created with view pager).When i click on the list item error occurs.I want to jump to inspiring fragment from categories fragment(fragment defined inside view pager). 
Categories (Tab Fragment created with view pager)

```
 public class Categories extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<CategoriesDataModel> list;
    private String[] categories={"Inspiring","Feelings","Strength","Hard Work","Success"};

    public Categories() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoriesList_Id);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            CategoriesDataModel dataModel = new CategoriesDataModel();

            dataModel.cat_name = categories[i];

            list.add(dataModel);
        }

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(list,getContext());
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout_inspiring,new Inspiring()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Inspiring :-

```
public class Inspiring extends Fragment {


    public Inspiring() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inspiring, container, false);
    }
}
```

Pager Adapter :-

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int tabCount=0;

    public Pager(FragmentManager fm,int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount=tabCount;
    }


    //this will return tab selected
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                return new Recents();

            case 1:
                return new Top();

            case 2:
                return new Categories();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find the `AndroidViewModel` of use in this case.

What you are doing is attempting to maintain state between different parts of your app.

If you have an `AndroidViewModel` attached to the Activity Lifecycle, you can observe that state in your Activity and make transactions to the `FragmentManager` to represent your choices.

## An example

### ViewModel

This ViewModel contains state data for which navigation item you are in (representing a `Fragment` with an integer in this case) and using an integer to represent an index for your inspiration row.

```
public class NavigationViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> navigationLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> inspirationLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public NavigationViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getNavigation() {
        return navigationLiveData;
    }

    public void setNavigation(Integer id) {
        navigationLiveData.postValue(id);
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getInspiration() {
        return inspirationLiveData;
    }

    public void setInspiration(Integer id) {
        inspirationLiveData.postValue(id);
    }
}
```

### Activity

The `Activity` will observe the navigation `LiveData` provided by our implementation of the `AndroidViewModel`. This will let it know immediately when a navigation change has been made.

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        navigationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NavigationViewModel.class);

        navigationViewModel.getNavigation().observe(this, id -> {
            switch(id) {
                case R.id.recents:
                    // TODO: Load recent fragment here with a transaction
                    break;
                case R.id.top:
                    // TODO: Load top fragment here with a transaction
                    break;
                case R.id.categories:
                    // TODO: Load categories fragment here with a transaction
                    break;
                case R.id.inspiring:
                    // TODO: Load inspiring fragment here with a transaction
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Inspiration Fragment

This `Fragment` will observe the inspiration index provided by our implementation of `AndroidViewModel`. That lets it know what content needs to be displayed. This can be set from *ANYWHERE*.

```
public class InspiringFragment extends Fragment {

    private NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inspiring, container, false);

        navigationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NavigationViewModel.class);

        navigationViewModel.getInspiration().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), inspiration -> {
            // TODO: Update the root view UI with data gleaned using the inspiration index given here
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

### Setting it

Once you have that, all you need to do is call:

```
navigationViewModel.setInspiration(1);
navigationViewModel.setNavigation(R.id.inspiration);
```

This should give you a good base to start with.